# is patching a better idea, with products available online for this scratch

Tags: scratch

[image]

[image]

I have recently rubbed through a plastic box which was left midway and it scratched my car along with another rack which helped it scratch my car.

My car was recently fully painted, I am looking to get this patched, the mechanic said there's a dent and requires full panel coating, although there's no dent and I felt he just want to overcharge me.

My question is whether I can use spray paints, available online and get this patched.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I hate to say this, but the mechanic is right. There is a dent there, something which I'd call a crease. You can easily tell this in the top photo ... you can see a color variation above and below the scratch. The top area is in shadow while the bottom area is in highlight. While it may be slight, there's a crease there which paint alone won't fix.

Comment: Aah that hurts, but as I was known of the circumstances where the incident happened, I strongly believe the contact was not that harsh to create a dent, even when I tough, it doesn't feel like bent. Tried to pour some soap water on it, didn't feel like there was scratch until it existed (followed a tip from ChrisFix channel to know whether the scratch is deep or clear coat). And the car's body is fully painted a couple of months ago.